# Eclipse won't display menu bar, menu item or JLabel

Tags: java, swing, constructor, jframe

regarding the code below, eclipse is giving me a lot of errors around line 72 to 86 (frame cannot be resolved) and i also can't see the label or add a menu bar, i think all issues are related and would appreciate if someone would cast a more experienced eye over it please.  Eric

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 


public class BookGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener

{


    //String addBook="";
    // public ArrayList<Book> books;

    //Book books = new Book ("", "", 0, "", 0);
    Book book = new Book("", "", 0, "", 0);
    String title  = "";
    String author  = "";
    int year = 0;
    String publisher  = "";
    double cost = 0;
    double total = 0;
    boolean goodInput = false;


    public BookShelf bookShelf = new BookShelf();
    public static final int WIDTH = 400;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 100;

    //Creates & displays a window of the class FlowLayoutDemo
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BookGUI gui = new BookGUI( );
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }

   // public String getTitle()
   // {
    //    return title;
    //}

    public void setTitle(String title) //this is relevant
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) //this is relevant
    {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) //this is relevant
    {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public void setPublisher(String publisher) //this is relevant
    {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public void setCost(double cost) //this is relevant
    {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public BookGUI( )
    {
        frame = new JFrame ("Books");
        Container contentpane = frame.getContentPane();

        JLabel label = new JLabel ("Book GUI");
        contentPane.add(label);

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JMenuItem quitItem = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        fileMenu.add(quitItem);;
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.red);

        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        addWindowListener(new WindowDestroyer( ));
        setTitle("GUI Assignment");
        Container content = getContentPane( );

        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Hightest Price Paid");
        content.add(button1);
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        //contentPane.add(button1);

        JButton button2 = new JButton("Cost of BookShelf");
        content.add(button2);
        button2.addActionListener(this);

        JButton button3 = new JButton("Size of BookShelf");
        content.add(button3);
        button3.addActionListener(this);

        JButton button4 = new JButton("Add Book");
        content.add(button4);
        button4.addActionListener(this); 

     // Alows the class to quit.
        //private void quit() 
            //System.exit(0);
           }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Add Book"))
       //book = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Add Book");
        {     //set up the book object with all the data passed in
        title = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Title");
        author = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Author");
        publisher = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Publisher");
        //cost = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cost");
        //cost = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cost"));
        do{
        try { 
            cost = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cost"));
            book.setCost(cost);
            goodInput = true;
            } 
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe){          
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Numerical entry required. Please try again");
            } 
        }while (!goodInput);


        book.setTitle(title);
        book.setAuthor(author);
        book.setPublisher(publisher);
        bookShelf.addBook(book);

        String message =  "The title of the book is :" + title + 
        "the Author of the Book is : " + author + " and it's published by " + publisher + "and it costs" + cost + "euro";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "Book Details", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Size of BookShelf")) {
            int sizeOfBookShelf = bookShelf.sizeOfBookshelf();
            String message = "The book shelf has " + sizeOfBookShelf + " book(s)";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, message);
        }
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Cost of BookShelf")) 
        {
            double costOfBookshelf = bookShelf.costOfBookShelf();
            String message = "The book shelf value is " + total + costOfBookshelf + "Euro";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, message);
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }

        System.exit( 0 ); 

     // Alows the class to quit.
        //private void quit() {
            //System.exit(0);

    }
    }
```

Comment: You've got a lot of commented lines at the end there. Are those really relevant to this question?

Comment: Isaac - no sorry meant to tidy it up before i posted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`frame` can't be identified because you never declared it.

`JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Books");`

vs.

`frame = new JFrame ("Books");`

You did, however, extend `JFrame`. Did you mean to use `this` instead of `frame`?

Comment: @Isaac - thanks a bunch, that was really staring me in the face but i'm new to this stuff.  file menu on line 87 and conentPAne on line 88 still say they can't be resolved, any idea why that is?

Comment: You declared `contentpane` with a lowercase 'p' and `fileMenu` is never declared.

Comment: Thanks, the code now runs without error but i've got two gui's  - one with my buttons and action listeners and the other has a title 'Books' but no file menu - i want to incorporate the label and file menu into my gui with the buttons, any suggestions?

Comment: If you want everything in one frame, then I would suggest only using one frame.